# Line Geometry predictions for angles and parallel points

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, line, point

I am making a drawing pen in three JS, and it is working fine, with the way I want, but I am missing out one feature and not getting an idea how to get that done.

when I click first, I am storing a point and then updating the line based on mouse move.
Now suppose I move the mouse down and click 2nd time, now one line is complete.
Next assume I am continuing back upwards from 2nd point and I want to show the helper line when mouse reach the same height of the first point. 
same should continue for all points. for example if my array contains some 200 points and I am about to draw 201th point, it should show predictions when mouse is moving to same height or some parallel x or y point positions.

[image: example image]
    What changes I should do in the code. below is the link of sample fiddle.

```js
var renderer, scene, camera;
var line;
var count = 0;
var mouse = new THREE.Vector3();

init();
animate();

function init() {

  // info
  var info = document.createElement('div');
  info.style.position = 'absolute';
  info.style.top = '30px';
  info.style.width = '100%';
  info.style.textAlign = 'center';
  info.style.color = '#fff';
  info.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  info.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  info.style.zIndex = '1';
  info.style.fontFamily = 'Monospace';
  info.innerHTML = "three.js - animated line using BufferGeometry";
  document.body.appendChild(info);

  // renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);

  // geometry
  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  var MAX_POINTS = 500;
  positions = new Float32Array(MAX_POINTS * 3);
  geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));

  // material
  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    linewidth: 2
  });

  // line
  line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
  scene.add(line);

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
}

// update line
function updateLine() {
  positions[count * 3 - 3] = mouse.x;
  positions[count * 3 - 2] = mouse.y;
  positions[count * 3 - 1] = mouse.z;
  line.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
}

// mouse move handler
function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  mouse.z = 0;
  mouse.unproject(camera);
  if( count !== 0 ){
   updateLine();
  }
}

// add point
function addPoint(event){
  console.log("point nr " + count + ": " + mouse.x + " " + mouse.y + " " + mouse.z);
  positions[count * 3 + 0] = mouse.x;
  positions[count * 3 + 1] = mouse.y;
  positions[count * 3 + 2] = mouse.z;
  count++;
  line.geometry.setDrawRange(0, count);
  updateLine();
}

// mouse down handler
function onMouseDown(evt) {
  // on first click add an extra point
  if( count === 0 ){
      addPoint();
  }
  addPoint();
}

// render
function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// animate
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.js"></script>
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/a21ey9y6/)

Comment: Somewhat difficult to do efficiently. Might need a spatial subdivision structure for fast queries if the number of points exceeds a few hundred.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog : do you have any ideas on how to start atleast based on my code .. later I will check efficiently